# Extjs 4 compare two timefieds that are columns of a Ext.grid.Panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Extjs 4 compare two timefieds that are columns of a Ext.grid.Panel? For instance a startTime should be < endTime

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't compare time *fields* but record values. For example:

```
Ext.Date.isEqual(record.get('startTime'), record.get('endTime'));
```